# Get all the cell values from excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to use the ExcelWorksheet object from the EPPlus library and retrieve all the cells with values as well as their positions.

At the end of the day, I want a dictionary similar to this.

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, object> values.
```

I am looking for a nice and clean way to extract the cell values into this dictionary for use.

I am quite aware that you can reference the cell values directly as below, but is there a nice clean way of extracting all the data ?

```
worksheet.Cells[row, column];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no native function in EPPlus to convert a the cells collection to a another collection directly but it does implement `IEnumerable` so you can do it fairly easily with `Linq` on the worksheet.  This works out nicely because `cells`only contains cell references that contain values so you do not even need to specify a row/column limit:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Cells_To_Dictionary_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066500/get-all-the-cell-values-from-excel-using-epplus

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(object)) });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i; 
        row[1] = i * 10;
        row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Grouped.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        pck.Save();
    }

    //Load a dictionary from a file
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

        //Cells only contains references to cells with actual data
        var cells = worksheet.Cells;
        var dictionary = cells
            .GroupBy(c => new {c.Start.Row, c.Start.Column})
            .ToDictionary(
                rcg => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column),
                rcg => cells[rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column].Value);

        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
            Console.WriteLine("{{ Row: {0}, Column: {1}, Value: \"{2}\" }}", kvp.Key.Key, kvp.Key.Value, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Which produces this in the output:

```
{ Row: 1, Column: 1, Value: "Col1" }
{ Row: 1, Column: 2, Value: "Col2" }
{ Row: 1, Column: 3, Value: "Col3" }
{ Row: 2, Column: 1, Value: "0" }
{ Row: 2, Column: 2, Value: "0" }
{ Row: 2, Column: 3, Value: "o103ujwu.hmq" }
{ Row: 3, Column: 1, Value: "1" }
{ Row: 3, Column: 2, Value: "10" }
{ Row: 3, Column: 3, Value: "awyajw2t.lwa" }
{ Row: 4, Column: 1, Value: "2" }
{ Row: 4, Column: 2, Value: "20" }
{ Row: 4, Column: 3, Value: "mjhlre2d.nh2" }
{ Row: 5, Column: 1, Value: "3" }
{ Row: 5, Column: 2, Value: "30" }
{ Row: 5, Column: 3, Value: "dypjvona.m3w" }
{ Row: 6, Column: 1, Value: "4" }
{ Row: 6, Column: 2, Value: "40" }
{ Row: 6, Column: 3, Value: "s5oushbr.sax" }
{ Row: 7, Column: 1, Value: "5" }
{ Row: 7, Column: 2, Value: "50" }
{ Row: 7, Column: 3, Value: "1vqjxxky.2gn" }
{ Row: 8, Column: 1, Value: "6" }
{ Row: 8, Column: 2, Value: "60" }
{ Row: 8, Column: 3, Value: "2dw00hi0.pjp" }
{ Row: 9, Column: 1, Value: "7" }
{ Row: 9, Column: 2, Value: "70" }
{ Row: 9, Column: 3, Value: "qgottyza.vnu" }
{ Row: 10, Column: 1, Value: "8" }
{ Row: 10, Column: 2, Value: "80" }
{ Row: 10, Column: 3, Value: "yx4tmvdp.2pq" }
{ Row: 11, Column: 1, Value: "9" }
{ Row: 11, Column: 2, Value: "90" }
{ Row: 11, Column: 3, Value: "jutk2r0v.1yx" }
```

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier  Humm..never tried it but I would think it be like mocking any other object.  If you only a few parts it should not be too difficult.  But if you need alot of WS functionality it maybe simpler to create a true worksheet in a memory stream with one of the other constructors of the package, i.e. something like `var pck = new ExcelPackage().`

Comment: `ExcelRange.Value` ?