# C# Joining Excel files

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am trying to join 3 Excel files together by rows in a column.

I am using `EPPlus` .NET library which work great but it's extremely slow.

I have to check row by row to find the corresponding value in the other Excels files.
Here my code:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= excelWorksheetVar.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
{
            for (int j = 3; j <= excelWorksheetBefore.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
            {
                if (excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 3].Text == excelWorksheetBefore.Cells[j, 1].Text)
                {
                    excelWorksheetBefore.Cells[j, 2, j, 4].Copy(excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 8, i, 10]);
                    excelWorksheetBefore.Cells[j, 6, j, 9].Copy(excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 11, i, 14]);
                }
                if (excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 3].Text == excelWorksheetAfter.Cells[j, 1].Text)
                {
                    excelWorksheetAfter.Cells[j, 2, j, 4].Copy(excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 15, i, 17]);
                    excelWorksheetAfter.Cells[j, 6, j, 9].Copy(excelWorksheetVar.Cells[i, 18, i, 21]);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

}

I am fetching all rows from column 3 in my first Excel file `excelWorksheetVar` and trying to find the corresponding value in the first column of the second Excel file `excelWorksheetBefore` and same with the third Excel file `excelWorksheetAfter`. If the value is found, it is writing the some columns of the row in the first Excel file.

What would be the fastest way if when files could be about 300k rows?
I am thinking about converting to a `DataTable` or something similar.

Comment: "I am thinking about converting to a DataTable or something similar. " Yes, do that.

Answer (score 0):

With that many rows EPPlus will be slow to load no matter what since it will load all of them into memory.  But if that count is spread out across three files then at least you can load them one at a time into the data tables.  If you try it using the method you are doing now then ALL 300K will have to be held in ram and crossed reference - very expensive and could even run out of memory.

You can load them into tables or even a dictionary using something like this:

[Get all the cell values from excel using EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066500/get-all-the-cell-values-from-excel-using-epplus/32073584#32073584)